# IndexError: tuple index out of range with psycopg2

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2

This code has no issues:

```
cursor.execute("select message from snippets where keyword=%s", (name,))
```

However, with this I get an `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

```
cursor.execute("select * from table where prescription like '\"%\"%s%'", (string,))
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The second snippet puts the variable inside a string literal (as it's surrounded by single quotes), so psycopg doesn't handle it. One way to solve this is to keep the placeholder form and perform the string manipulation in your Python code before binding it:

```
name = '%%%s%%' % name
cursor.execute("select * from table where prescription like %s", (name,))
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to enter a literal `%` in the query you have to use `%%`.